# What will be the principal id for response from custom Lambda authorizer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am writing a custom authorizer Lambda which will be invoked every time my API gateway gets a request. I am validating my third party token. 
As a response, I see the Lambda has to return a Principal ID and a policy.
I am using Java and would like to know what the principal Id would be and how I can produce it? Is it a part of my token?

Answer (score 1):

Extracted from [this thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=703105):

> The principalId is intended to represent the long term identifier for whatever entity is being authorized to make the API call. So if you have an existing database of users, each user presumably has a unique identifier or username. You mentioned 'user', which is probably fine. Functionally, the principalId is logged if you enable CloudWatch Logs, and is also what you can access in the $context for mapping templates